# Как тестировать функцию, в которой есть обращение к базе данных (с помощью Jest)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, юнит-тесты, jest

Тестирую серверную функцию с помощью Jest.

Я упростил функцию, оставил ключевые моменты.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как замокать запрос к db, чтобы не было реального обращения к базе данных.

```
import { db } from '../../../firebase/admin.js';
...

export async function updateUser(req, res) {
  try {

    const noValid = validate(req);
    if (noValid) return res.status(400).json({ error: noValid });
    
   
    await db.doc(`users/${req.body.userId}`).update(req.body);
   

    return res.json({ message: `Данные профиля пользователя обновлены.` });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ general: err });
  }
};
```

была мысль чтобы при передачи 3го аргумента обходилось обращение к db но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не оптимально, придётся во все функции с обращение к db добавлять такую контрукцию:

```
export async function updateUser(req, res, test) {
  ...

  if (test)
    return res.json({ message: `Данные профиля пользователя обновлены.` })

  else 
    await db.doc(`users/${req.body.userId}`).update(req.body);

  ...
```